# Windows key not "waiting" for another key

Tags: windows-8.1, keyboard-shortcuts

So my Windows 8.1 recently updated, and I don't know if this is the cause of my problem, but it started after the update.

The problem: when I press Windows key it doesn't wait for me to release it before showing the Start Screen, so whenever I want to use it together with another key on a shortcut, it always shows the Start Screen before anything, and I don't want that.

Example: I want to minimize everything and I press Windows + D, but it shows the start screen. I'm still holding down the Windows key when I press D, I'm doing the correct way, but the system shows me the start screen instead of the Desktop.

Is there a way to fix that? Maybe on settings somewhere there's an option for that?

PS.: Sorry if this question already exists, I tried looking for it and didn't find anything.

Comment: Weird thing is that my computer at work also updated this week (also 8.1) and I can press as long as I want the Windows key and it will not show me the Start Screen until I release it. Do you think this could be a hardware problem with my laptop?

Comment: Did you try another keyboard?

Comment: @Psycogeek Ok I will do that when I get home.

Comment: @thims didn't try another keyboard because I don't have one to try.

Comment: Buy/borrow another keyboard then as you'll need to rule this out. In the mean time, you may be able to use AutoHotKey to get you by

Comment: @Dave I will do that.

Comment: That seems much more likely , another input driver, causing issues.

Comment: The problem was the Synaptics Driver, the same issue Piotr Truszkowski had. Thanks guys!

Comment: Just to let everyone know, there's a new Synaptics Driver available on Windows Update that solves this issue.
(I can't comment on Piotr's question because of my low rep).